# PHP conditionals for $message in mail

Tags: php, email, message

I know there is a simpler way to do this. What I'm trying to do is group fields by number and use isset to test if $_POST['item#'] value is empty. If that item# is not empty, I want to send corresponding color, quantity, and price. If there is more than one item submitted, I want to send multiples.

Here are my post variables:

```
$item1 = $_POST['item1'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$quantity1 = $_POST['quantity1'];
$price1 = $_POST['price1'];

$item2 = $_POST['item2'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$quantity2 = $_POST['quantity2'];
$price2 = $_POST['price2'];

$item3 = $_POST['item3'];
$color3 = $_POST['color3'];
$quantity3 = $_POST['quantity3'];
$price3 = $_POST['price3'];

$item4 = $_POST['item4'];
$color4 = $_POST['color4'];
$quantity4 = $_POST['quantity4'];
$price4 = $_POST['price4'];

$item5 = $_POST['item5'];
$color5 = $_POST['color5'];
$quantity5 = $_POST['quantity5'];
$price5 = $_POST['price5'];

$item6 = $_POST['item6'];
$color6 = $_POST['color6'];
$quantity6 = $_POST['quantity6'];
$price6 = $_POST['price6'];

$item7 = $_POST['item7'];
$color7 = $_POST['color7'];
$quantity7 = $_POST['quantity7'];
$price7 = $_POST['price7'];

$item8 = $_POST['item8'];
$color8 = $_POST['color8'];
$quantity8 = $_POST['quantity8'];
$price8 = $_POST['price8'];


I'm using isset to test if $_POST[] values are empty:

if( isset($_POST['item1']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item1." \nColor: ".$color1." \nQuantity: ".$quantity1." \nPrice: ".$price1;

}

if( isset($_POST['item2']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item2." \nColor: ".$color2." \nQuantity: ".$quantity2." \nPrice: ".$price2;
}

if( isset($_POST['item3']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item3." \nColor: ".$color3." \nQuantity: ".$quantity3." \nPrice: ".$price3;
}

if( isset($_POST['item4']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item4." \nColor: ".$color4." \nQuantity: ".$quantity4." \nPrice: ".$price4;
}

if( isset($_POST['item5']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item5." \nColor: ".$color5." \nQuantity: ".$quantity5." \nPrice: ".$price5;
}
if( isset($_POST['item6']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item6." \nColor: ".$color6." \nQuantity: ".$quantity6." \nPrice: ".$price6;
}
if( isset($_POST['item7']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item7." \nColor: ".$color6." \nQuantity: ".$quantity7." \nPrice: ".$price7;
}
if( isset($_POST['item7']) )
{
    $message = 'Item: '.$item8." \nColor: ".$color7." \nQuantity: ".$quantity8." \nPrice: ".$price8;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html content where this POST comes from? Because we'd better simplify html structure also.

Comment: I tried to but I haven't posted enough to reply already.

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = $_POST['item'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    if ($items[$i])){  //not necessarily the best way to check if it has a value
        //do what you want with $items[$i], $color[$i], $quantity[$i], and $price[$]
    }
}
```

For your HTML form inputs use:

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" />
```

Comment: But he does not know exact length of items. Because he did html wrong way, coiuld do much simpler.

Comment: you should use `foreach`

Comment: Forgive me, you should not use foreach, since there are multiple values that will depend on the location in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the requested HTML. I'm just learning so I'm sure there is a more efficient way to name inputs. I'm trying to group item-color-quantity-price, so that when the form is emailed, the relevant data is in a paragraph or table for each item.

```
<td align="center"><p><span>Item Name</span><br><input id="item1" type="text" name="item1"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><span>Color</span><br><input id="color1" type="text" name="color1"></td>
<td align="center"><p><span>Quantity</span><br><input id="quantity1" type="text" name="quantity1"></td>
<td align="center"><p><span>Wholesale Price</span><br><input id="price1" type="text" name="price1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item2"  type="text" name="item2"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color2" type="text" name="color2"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input  id="quantity2" type="text" name="quantity2"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price2" type="text" name="price2"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item3" type="text" name="item3"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color3" type="text" name="color3"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity3" type="text" name="quantity3"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price3" type="text" name="price3"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item4" type="text" name="item4"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color4" type="text" name="color4"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity4" type="text" name="quantity4"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price4" type="text" name="price4"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item5" type="text" name="item5"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color5" type="text" name="color5"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity5" type="text" name="quantity5"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price5" type="text" name="price5"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item6" type="text" name="item6"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color6" type="text" name="color6"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity6" type="text" name="quantity6"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price6" type="text" name="price6"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item7" type="text" name="item7"></p></td>
<td align="center"><input id="color7" type="text" name="color7"></p></td>
<td align="center"><input id="quantity7" type="text" name="quantity7"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price7" type="text" name="price7"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item8" type="text" name="item8"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color8" type="text" name="color8"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity8" type="text" name="quantity8"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price8"type="text" name="price8"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><p><input id="item9" type="text" name="item9"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="color9"  type="text" name="color9"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="quantity9" type="text" name="quantity9"></p></td>
<td align="center"><p><input id="price9" type="text" name="price9"></p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For each input field, you should remove the number and replace it with `[]`. This way, when you `POST` the data, it will be an array and then @viakondratiuk's answer pretty much would take care of it. Also, unless you need specifically 6 sets of inputs, you should/could start with one set of inputs on the page, include an `add` button that would put in another set of inputs via `Javascript`.

Comment: The data filled out in the form will be `POST`ed with just the values, then you can re-build it into an email-able HTML form within your `PHP` script.

Answer (score 0):

I converted all my input names to arrays and I have working loop. However, I need to format the foreach to produce an HTML email with table. It was working perfectly when echo-ing the data but once I formatted it to send as $message, it only sends the last $item.

Here is the foreach loop that works perfectly:

```
foreach ( $_POST['item'] as $items) {
    {
       echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '  <td>', $items['name'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $items['color'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $items['size'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $items['quantity'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $items['price'], '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

HTMl email using the PHP mail function:

foreach ( $_POST['item'] as $items) {

```
$message = "
   <html>
   <body>
   <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>" . $items['name'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $items['color'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $items['size'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $items['quantity'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $items['price'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
}
```